# What is the proper Authorization Code OAuth2 flow?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm currently unfamiliar with the OAuth2.0 Authorization Code Flow and I've read many articles about it and currently I still don't know how to properly implement it. So far, what I know about the flow:

1. User Logs in using OAuth
2. User is redirected to the authorization server for authorization code
3. Callback for permission/scope
4. Redirected to authorization server for access token in exchange for authorization code
5. Redirect back to the client with the access token
6. Client uses access token to access resource server.

Right now, what I'm still confused is that where should the login validation come (Login of username - password)? Is it a separate validation before going to OAuth flow and once the user is valid, it should go back to the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some resources that explain [OAuth 2.0 using Google Sign in as an example](https://dev.to/cotter/what-on-earth-is-oauth-a-super-simple-intro-to-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-and-how-to-implement-it-in-your-site-48jo). Let me try to rephrase it according to your question.

**Let's use the example of a user logging-in to Intercom using "Sign in with Google".**

1. The user presses the button "Sign in with Google". This will redirect to the identity providers `/authorize` endpoint (could be different for each provider) which go to their login page.
2. The user is redirected to Google's accounts page. If not already logged-in, the user can **enter their Google email/password** here.
3. Google redirects back to Intercom with an `authorization_code` (for example, it redirects to `https://intercom.com/authcallback?code=XYZ...`)
4. Intercom's backend server sends this `authorization_code` with the `client_id` and `client_secret` (from their project in google), and receive an `access_token` (usually to the `/token` endpoint)
5. Intercom can then use the `access_token` to access the user's profile from Google.

So to answer your question, **the user can enter their email/password inside the OAuth provider's page**. Keep in mind that *OAuth 2.0 doesn't specify how the provider is authenticating the user*. This means, that the OAuth provider can authenticate their users in different ways, like email/password, [email magic-link, SMS OTP](https://docs.cotter.app/quickstart-guides/react-magic-link-with-email-and-phone), etc. Your website is just supposed to trust the OAuth provider that they are authenticating the user for you correctly.

---

Some extra resources that would help you understand OAuth 2.0 more:

- [How to store the OAuth 2.0 access and refresh token in your front end](https://dev.to/cotter/localstorage-vs-cookies-all-you-need-to-know-about-storing-jwt-tokens-securely-in-the-front-end-15id)
- [Picking the right OAuth 2.0 flow](https://dev.to/cotter/oauth-2-0-before-you-start-pick-the-right-flow-for-your-website-spa-mobile-app-tv-app-and-cli-17n4)

Comment: Thanks for the response, this means that the login validation is separate from the flow, right? After the successful login from the provider, the authorize endpoint will be called?

Comment: Yes, the login validation is separate from the flow.

You would call the /authorize endpoint to go to Google's Login page. So the authorize endpoint will be called before the login is successful.

1. Call /authorize to go to Google's Login Page
2. User login successfully in Google's login page
3. Google redirect back to your app to https://example.com/authcallback?code=123...
and so on

Answer (score 0):

*login validation come (Login of username - password)?*

[OAuth 2.0 NOT an Authentication protocol](https://twitter.com/ve7jtb/status/740650395735871488)

[The OAuth 2.0 specification defines a delegation protocol](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication//)

Any use of username - password is outside of OAuth 2.0 and you should be looking at Open ID Connect which is an authentication protocol built on top of OAuth 2.0.

[Best current Practice for Authorization Code flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-15) is to use [PKCE](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/) on OAuth or OpenID Connect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you also explain when the user is redirected to a separate login page? What is the flow of that? Is it also a part of the OAuth? That is the part where I am confused right now

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to externalise both OAuth 2.0 and Open Id Connect from your code by using a mature security library. When you're new to this type of security there is a learning curve. My resources will give you an idea of how it all fits together:

- [Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1)
- [Tutorial Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)

The libraries you integrate depend on the technology stack you are using. The resources above are for a Single Page App and NodeJS API.